# Cannot deploy to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

```
08:38 AM Scanning files on local disk.
2013-01-30 08:38:30,884 ERROR appcfg.py:1856 Invalid character in filename: Icon

Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user SLim is already in progress for app: s~pekkylab, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---
Password for myemail@email.com: If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 1 ***
```

**While i'm trying to upload i got this error and then follow its instructor to perform rollback then i getting the other error here**

```
08:41 AM Application: pekkylab
08:41 AM Host: appengine.google.com
08:41 AM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4377, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4368, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2605, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4103, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3553, in Rollback
    self._Rollback()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3569, in _Rollback
    appversion.Rollback()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2151, in Rollback
    self.Send('/api/appversion/rollback')
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1842, in Send
    return self.rpcserver.Send(url, payload=payload, **self.params)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 391, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib/fancy_urllib/__init__.py", line 379, in do_open
    url_error.reason.args[1])
fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host appengine.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl
```

**Any clue why is this happening?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you are working on a MacOS and this file is the `Icon?` (read more on [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/298798/32981)). You can easily verify it if you list all the files from your terminal: `ls`.

In order to skip that file add this in end of your `app.yaml` file and redeploy:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?Icon\r
```

You can read more on [skipping files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Skipping_Files) in the docs.

Also you might need to rollback before redeploying:

```
appcfg.py rollback /path/to/project
```

And if nothing works out for you, just try to deploy to a new application and try again another day :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. btw, after i added the line it will simply skip all files :/

Comment: @SLim, That's strange.. try `- ^(.*/)?Icon*` or `- ^Icon*` or `- ^Icon?`

Comment: @SLim.. oh sorry.. you might still going to get the 409.. because you started the deployment but never finished.. try as suggested to rollback... `appcfg.py rollback .`

Comment: Yea.. i tried all it will still skipping all the files. then i try to view the hidden files, finally i found something exist without my notice - Icon i just delete it and removed the line then try again.. it's still Error 409. then follow your suggestion of rollback it state directory dont have app.yaml file. may i know are not the dir for running rollback should be /usr/local/bin ?

Comment: @SLim the dir for the rollback should be the one that contains the app.yaml.. if you delete that file then everything will be fine.. but the line as suggested in the answer should work as well.. now you need to rollback to get rid of the 409

Comment: the bottom part of my question is what i keep on getting while rolling back :(

Comment: @SLim, Try creating a new application and deploy there.. don't know why you are getting that..

Comment: Yea... so the final solution is creating a new application.. lol

Comment: please add on something to your answer for accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is some exotic character in the filename of an icon, as the log states.
Rename it, and update your application to use the renamed version.

You should rollback the transaction manually ("appcfg rollback"), and then try to deploy again.

Comment: I never adding any extra file but just update some line of code

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy with the parameter no_cookies in that fashion `appcfg.py update . --no_cookies`

Comment: The above are results returned

Comment: The bottom part of my question is what i get while running this update :/

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a custom icon for your app folder... That generate a "hidden" Icon file, delete it.